# How do I debug an executable that is called by a batch file within that context?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2012

I'm running into a tricky little problem. I have a compiled C# executable that is called with arguments in a batch file. I would like to run this executable through the VS2012 debugger, however I am unsure of how to attach the debugger to the executable as it is run from the batch script.

I am not able to set the batch script as the project's debug startup file (only .exes), and the only process I can find that is associated with the batch file is cmd.exe, which does not allow for debugging. I have added a `pause` to the beginning of the batch script so ideally the process should be running and I should be able to attach it, but I can't find anything of the expected name.

Anyone know how to do this? It seems like a pretty straightforward problem but I can't quite figure out how to get it into the debugger.

Comment: Can't you just provide the same command-line parameters to Properties|Debug|Start Options and debug your app that way?

Comment: I can, and the arguments would be fine, but I'm also trying to test that logging out output / exceptions occurs correctly and this is handled in the batch file. Console output in the executable is transcribed to files, and I would ideally like to ensure that this is working correctly in the context of the batch script.

Comment: Add a pause in your executable (use `#If DEBUG` if you want) to give you enough time to attach the debugger in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or simply add a `Debugger.Launch()` at the start of your code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

It will prompt you with all available VS debuggers, choose the one your are currently using.

See link for more information: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Add this line:

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail("stopping!");`

to a good place in your code.  Run your app.  Hit "Retry" and you should be prompted for a debugger.  Choose 
Visual Studio.

**Edit**:

jp.gauthier's solution to use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` is much cleaner.  Upvote his instead.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Two things here: You cannot debug the batch script using the VS debugger. So when your exe returns the result is picked up by the script but you can't single-step trough that. To debug a batch script, flood it with `pause` commands and leave `echo on` to see what's going on.

To attach to your exe when it is started from the script, there are a couple of possibilities. One is (temporarily) modifying the exe to wait at startup a certain time (a few seconds or so) so you have time to attach the debugger. There's even a Win32 function to check whether a debugger is attached, if you want to. I remember having seen a possibility using the registry to automatically launch a process with the debugger, but I can't recall the exact procedure now.

Edit: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984846/set-image-file-execution-options-will-always-open-the-named-exe-file-as-defaul) a topic describing the idea in short (answer 1).

Answer (score 1):

Windows provides a way to start a debugger for any executable by setting the Registry value [Image File Execution Options (MSDN on archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170801222944/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(vs.71).aspx). The article describes exactly what you need: starting Visual Studio as the debugger.

1. Create the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\<Yourapp>.exe`.
2. Create a String called `Debugger`
3. Set the value to `devenv /debugexe`

Don't forget to remove it when done.

Comment: link is dead, it's a microsoft link so of course it's dead...

Comment: @fartwhif: I replaced it by an archive.org link instead